# on:keydown event with Enter Key in svelte

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, svelte, onkeydown

I am using svelte with an `on:click` event on a button. When this button is clicked, I dispatch some information to a higher component. What I would like to do is hit the enter key instead, but `on:keydown` doesn't seem to work? How can I get this to fire when hitting enter?

```
<button on:click={() => 
   dispatch('search', { searchword: item })}
>ClickMe</button>
```

```
<button on:keydown={() => 
   dispatch('search', { searchword: item })}
>PressEnter</button>
```

Comment: Enter already causes the `click` event by default. Having buttons that cannot be clicked violates user expectations.

Comment: I see, so then there must be another issue I am not seeing. probably my x state management

Comment: well, does the button have focus?

Comment: I am thinking that is what is wrong, it probably doesn't

Comment: usually for searches you have a `<form>` containing an `<input>` and a `<button>`, then Enter in the input will cause the submit button of the form to be clicked (by default the `type` of  the button will be `submit`). This also causes a form submission (`submit` event), which might need to be cancelled (`preventDefault`) to prevent a page reload)

Comment: excellent! this is someone elses code so I will look into it but that helps alot. its weird cuz when i click the button it works but not on enter

Answer (score 13):

Enter will automatically fire `click` if the button has focus or is part of a form and is clicked implicitly as part of the form submission.

Generally I would recommend using a form, then Enter within an `<input>` will cause a form submission. One can then also directly work with the form's `submit` event, as that may need cancelling anyway, unless the page reload is desired.

Example:

```html
<script>
    let value = '';
    let submittedValue = null;
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={() => submittedValue = value}>
    <label>
        Search
        <input bind:value />
    </label>
    
    <button on:click={() => console.log('button clicked')}>GO</button>
</form>

{#if submittedValue != null}
    <p>Submitted: {submittedValue}</p>
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/eda7ac5b71d047fabfb626712ad00554?version=3.47.0)

Comment: Thank you, I am finding that this button is not part of a form, and they are using x state to navigate and give focus to things. Its more complicated than I thought.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - very clearly described, and after testing against your scenario seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

The issue was a state machine giving focus/ not giving focus. This project was using xstate to manage alot.